# NginX Ingress problem with ? in URL when using path based routing

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using the nginx ingress controller with an AKS cluster.

The problem I have at the moment is that whenever a query string is added to a URL, nginx returns a 502 bad gateway.

The ingress is:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: dh2
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: myapp-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp-1680613380
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "example.com"
      secretName: qa-tls
  rules:
    - host: "example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-1680613380
                port:
                  number: 80
```

When I access http://example.com everything works as expected. However if I pass any query string in the URL such as http://example.com/login?=1 I receive a 502.

I have tried to use Regex with the following annotation and path:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
...
path: /(.*)
```

But this also fails to work. What am I missing?

Comment: You checked the nginx log?

Comment: Good point, I see this [error] 27#27: *364434 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream when I check the query string requests? So perhaps it is failing and just throwing a 502 rather than a 414?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes very true @Turing85, will try and remember that next time, just force of habit to come to stack first :D I will post an answer to the above anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Rafael was onto something.

Having checked the controller logs it seems that an error was being thrown about the length of the URL.

Naturally I would have thought that nginx should have then thrown a 414 error but instead resorted to a 502. Since the issue is not with my ingress code Turing is correct that this should now be moved to ServerFault.

However all I needed to do with increase the buffer sizes on the nginx controller config map since it appears nginx has very small buffer sizes by default.

I simply added the following under data:

```
  proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
  large-client-header-buffers: "4 16k"
```